# Is it possible to pass variables from a BASH Script into PWSH on Linux

Tags: bash, powershell, variables

We have a project where we want to run some Bash & Powershell scripts on Linux. We will be using a BASH Script to run some processes with various variables, execute a powershell script & then complete some more BASH commands.

If we have variables set in the bash script and then we execute the powershell script in the same BASH session, is there a way to pass those variables across to Powershell?

Answer (score 4):

You can pass values via *environment variables*, which Bash (and POSIX-compatible shells in general) makes easy:

```
$ foo='BAR'; bar='BAZ' # define sample Bash shell vars.
$ foo="$foo" bar="$bar" pwsh -noprofile -command '$env:foo; $env:bar'
BAR
BAZ
```

Note how prepending `foo="$foo"` and `bar="$bar"` defined *shell* variables `$foo` and `$bar` as *process-scoped environment variables* for the `pwsh` call.
That is, these environment variables are only in effect for the `pwsh` child process.

Alternatives:

- You can define environment variables separately, beforehand - e.g., 
  `export foo='BAR'`, but note that these stay in effect for the lifetime of the current process that the `bash` script runs in (unless you undefine them later).
- To make *all* variables in your `bash` script environment variables *automatically* (again for the lifetime of the current process), you can place a `set -a` statement before you create your regular shell variables. Then a regular assignment such as `foo='BAR'` automatically creates `foo` as an environment variable that PowerShell can access as `$env:foo`.

Comment: While this works, I've tried several combinations when using `-File` as opposed to `-Command`. This doesn't seem to work when using `-File`. Not a knock against this answer, though, because it _does_ work when using `-Command`.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight, pass-through arguments to a `-File` script are by design _literal_ arguments; thus, the target script itself would have to use `$env:` references inside the script. You can find more info about `-File` vs. `-Command` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).

Comment: Yup, understood that _inside_ a script, variables use the `$env:` prefix. But, when using environment variables to parameters to the file, e.g. `pwsh -File the-script.ps1 -Param1 $SOME_VAR`, nothing seemed t work correctly. Let me clarify, _this_ didn't seem to work: `SOME_VAR="a value" pwsh -File the-script.ps1 -Param "$SOME_VAR"`.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight, your approach would only work if you defined `SOME_VAR="a value"` _in a separate statement_ (and therefore only as a _shell_ variable). Your command is conceptually flawed in that _Bash_ would try to expand `$SOME_VAR` _up front_ - but `$SOME_VAR` isn't defined in the calling shell (it is only defined as an ephemeral env. var. for the _child_ process being invoked). Try `FOO='not yet' /bin/echo "[$FOO]"` (on one line).

Comment: Interesting, because when I do this, it works: `SOME_VAR="a value" pwsh -Command "& { .\the-script.ps1 -Param1 \"\${env:SOME_VAR}\""`. (I just had _other_ issues using this approach not related to this specific thing at hand ;) ).

Comment: If I understand what you're saying, after thinking about it a bit more, when using `-File` and "pre-creating" the environment variable `SOME_VAR`, in the _current shell_, `SOME_VAR` doesn't yet exist, and so using `-File the-script.ps1 -Param1 $SOME_VAR` doesn't work. The reason the `-Command` version works is because _we've already_ shelled to execute `pwsh`, and so in that subshell, `$SOME_VAR` exists.

Comment: Correct, @fourpastmidnight (except that `pwsh` isn't a _subshell_ in the Bash sense, it is an unrelated child process that itself happens to be a (different) shell).

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear the explanations were helpful, @fourpastmidnight; my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

If you export a bash variable it will be available in powershell as $env:variablename:

```
example=/var/data
export example
pwsh -noprofile -command '$env:example;'
```

returns 
/var/data

In Powershell you can run **Get-ChildItem Env:** to list all environment variables.