# Running a powershell command using full path and arguments from command line

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-prompt

I have a script that sits in `Program Files` folder and accepts arguments: `verbose` and `restart`
Running it from its folder works perfectly:

```
powershell ./<file.ps1> -verbose:$True -restart
```

Trying to run it using full path is where I have issues:

```
powershell & "C:\Program Files\Folder\<file.ps1> -verbose:$True -restart"
```

Above command doesn't run the script; Instead it's opening the PS command prompt and when exiting it, it opens the script in notepad.
I also tried to put each variable in a separate quote but that didn't work as well.

I found a workaround by using `progra~1` instead of `Program Files` but I'd like to solve the issue the proper way.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<sup>As an aside: The quoting-related part of the problem could have been avoided by using environment variable `$env:ProgramFiles` instead of literal `"C:\Program Files\..."` in the script path, which would have simplified the command to:

`powershell "& $env:ProgramFiles\Folder\file.ps1 -verbose:$True -restart"`</sup>

---

Indeed, **in order to execute scripts referenced by literal paths with embedded spaces** in PowerShell, those **paths must be *quoted* and the quoted path must be *passed to `&` or `.`***

However, when using [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) it is **simpler to use `-File` (`-f`) to execute a script**, which makes `&` unnecessary and simplifies quoting:

```
powershell -File "C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1" -Verbose -Restart
```

When PowerShell is called *from the outside*, **arguments that follow `-File` are taken *literally*** (after removing syntactic `"..."`, if present) - they are *not* interpreted the way they would be if you ran the command from *inside* PowerShell; e.g., **when calling from *outside* PowerShell, `powershell -File script.ps1 $env:USERNAME` would pass string `$env:USERNAME` *verbatim* to `script.ps1`  rather than expanding it** - if you need that, use `-Command`.

**Use `-Command` (`-c`) only if you need to pass a *snippet of PowerShell code* and/or arguments script-file arguments must be interpreted as they would from *inside* PowerShell**:

```
powershell -Command "& 'C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1' -Verbose:$true -Restart"
```

Note: `-Command` is notably needed in order to be able to pass *arrays* as script-file arguments; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54260497/45375).

The crucial improvements to your attempt are:

- `&` is placed inside `"..."`, which prevents `cmd.exe` from interpreting it *itself*, *before* PowerShell sees it.
- The script path is enclosed in *embedded* quoting (`'...'`), so that PowerShell sees the path as quoted.

Note:

- `-Command` is used for clarity; in *Windows PowerShell*, it can be omitted (as you did), because it is the *default* parameter; note, however, that in PowerShell *Core* the default is now `-File`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136129/45375) for a comprehensive overview of the two PowerShell CLIs.
- You don't strictly need to pass everything as *one* `"..."` string, but it is conceptually clearer that way.

See below for details.

Also note that **how the (process) *exit code* is set differs between `-File` and `-Command`** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

---

As for **what you tried**:

> Above command doesn't run the script; Instead it's opening the PS command prompt and when exiting it, it opens the script in notepad.

This implies that **you're calling from `cmd.exe`** (from the Command Prompt or a batch file), where **an `&` not enclosed in `"..."` has special meaning**: it is the *command-sequencing* operator.

That is, your command is the equivalent of the following *2* commands, executed *in sequence*:

```
powershell
"C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1 -verbose:$True -restart"
```

The 1st command opens an *interactive* PowerShell session.
Only after you manually exit it does the 2nd command get executed.

Note that your specific symptom suggests that you used only `"C:\Program Files\Folder\<file.ps1>"`, without arguments, as the 2nd command, which would indeed open that script file as a *document*, for *editing*.

*With* the arguments, the entire double-quoted string is interpreted as a filename, and you'll get the usual `... is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

In order **for `cmd.exe` to pass a `&` *through* to a command being invoked, it must either be enclosed in `"..."`, or, outside of such a string, escaped as `^&`**.

However, even fixing that *one* problem isn't enough:

```
rem # !! Still doesn't work
powershell ^& "C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1 -verbose:$True -restart"
```

The other problem is that when you use the `-Command` CLI parameter, which is *implied* in your case, PowerShell uses the following logic to process the arguments:

- Each argument is stripped of its enclosing `"..."`, if present.
- The stripped arguments are concatenated with spaces.
- The resulting single string is *then* executed as PowerShell code.

That is, with the above command PowerShell tried to execute a string with the following verbatim content:

```
& C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1 -verbose:$True -restart
```

As you can see, the script file path, which contains a space, lacks the necessary quoting.

You have several options to provide the necessary quoting around the script path:

---

**If you know that your script path does *not* contain `'` chars**, use *embedded* `'...'` quoting:

```
powershell -Command "& 'C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1' -Verbose:$true -Restart"
```

With only a single, outer pair of `"` chars., you needn't worry about `cmd.exe` inadvertently interpreting your arguments *up front*, before they reach PowerShell.

You *could* also omit the outer quoting in this case, but that makes the *unquoted* arguments susceptible to unwanted interpretation by `cmd.exe` (though it's fine in this case), and note that `'` has no special meaning in `cmd.exe`, so a PowerShell-style `'...'` string is considered *unquoted* by `cmd.exe`:

```
rem # Works, but generally less robust than the above.
powershell -Command ^& 'C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1' -Verbose:$true -Restart
```

---

**If you want to ensure that even paths with embedded `'` chars. work properly**:

Use embedded *double*-quoting, with the `"` escaped as `\"` (sic):

```
powershell -Command "& \"C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1\" -Verbose:$true -Restart"
```

Unfortunately, this again makes the string between the `\"` instances subject to potentially unwanted interpretation by `cmd.exe`.

You can work around this by using `\""` (sic) instead, but that makes the string between the `\""` instances subject to *whitespace normalization*: that is, multiple spaces in a row are folded into one.

In *Windows PowerShell*, you can avoid that by using `"^""` (sic), but note that in PowerShell *Core* you'll get the same behavior as with `\""`, but there you can use `""`, which works robustly.

```
rem # The most robust form in Windows PowerShell.
rem # Still subject to whitespace normalization in PowerShell Core.
powershell -Command "& "^""C:\Program Files\Folder\file.ps1"^"" -Verbose:$true -Restart"
```

Comment: I love the amount of detail here and the number of good examples.