# batch-file pauses after execution of powershell command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

What I am trying to do is to set -ExecutionPolicy (allow scripts) for the actual process (cmd.exe)

If a write this command in cmd.exe (as Administrator):

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

Output is:

```
Windows PowerShell 
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

Lernen Sie das neue plattformübergreifende PowerShell kennen – https://aka.ms/pscore6
```

Than I put on this command:

```
PowerShell.exe -Command "SomePowerShellScript.ps"
```

And all works.

If I try the same from a batch-file, it pauses after the first command.

The reason why I use the first command and not the Powershell specific with Set-ExecutionPolicy is described by Microsoft:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-5.1

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

--> sets ExecutionPolicy to cmd and powershell (script can be started)

```
PowerShell.exe -Command Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process
```

--> sets Policy only on actual powershell.exe process (script is not allowed to start)

And for clarifing I don't want to set execution policy to Unrestricted for LocalMachine/CurrentUser if possible.

For explaning this problem, the batch-file is only for "lazy" people to directly start the Powershell-Script without having to set ExecutionPolicy (So it works by double clicking).

Has anyone an idea why the batch-file pauses after the first command (I also tried it with call powershell.exe)?

Thanks for a response :).

Comment: Why do you use a Batch file? Much more easier is to create a simple link (shortcut) file: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file "D:\mypowershell\myscript.ps1"

Comment: `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted  -Command "SomePowerShellScript.ps"` should work smoothly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The apparent pause is a result of `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` actually entering an *interactive* PowerShell session, which you must manually `exit` (aside from that, the execution policy is set for that session (process) only).

If you place `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted` (or `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`) before a `-File` argument, the execution policy is set - for the process only - before execution of the script file passed to `-File` is attempted, and execution should succeed (unless a group policy preempts overriding the persistently configured execution policy on the command line:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File SomePowerShellScript.ps1
```

You can also use `-Command`, but note that this changes the interpretation of the arguments; notably, you must then use `.\SomePowerShellScript.ps1` to refer to the script to execute.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for more information.