# How to pass a string array to powershell through vbscript?

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I'm trying to pass a string array to powershell through vbscript.
I got the params in the file.ps1 script:

```
param (
    [string[]]$target
)
```

I'm trying to call file.ps1 through vbscript.

I want `$target = @('c:\dev','d:\lib')`  to be passed in.

I currently have in my vbscript :-

```
target1 = """c:\dev"", ""d:\lib"""
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
objShell.run("powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file .\file.ps1 -target1 """ & target & """")
```

which returns:
`c:\dev, d:\lib` and which isn't the powershell string array format `"c:\dev", "d:\lib"`

Update - Thanks **mklement0** and **alex-dl** for your answers!

Comment: Remove the `""` on each side - otherwise you're passing the literal string value `"c:\dev, d:\lib"`

Comment: removing "" would cause a syntax error. In vbscript " is used as the escape character. so if i was to print `"""c:\dev"", ""d:\lib"""` into vb console it would return `"c:\dev", "d:\lib"`

Comment: No it would not, `"... -target " & target & ""` is a perfectly valid expression

Comment: @Mathias, true, though the `& ""` is then unnecessary. The fundamental problem here, however, is the use of the `-File` CLI parameter, which fundamentally doesn't support passing _arrays_; `-Command` (`-c`) must be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[alex-dl's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66064804/45375) contains an effective solution, as long as the array's elements don't need quoting, but let me try to break it down conceptually in more detail:

- The **`-File` parameter** of PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), `powershell.exe` ([`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) in PowerShell (Core) 7+) fundamentally **does *not* support passing *arrays* to PowerShell code, because all arguments are interpreted strictly as *whitespace*-separated, with *verbatim* content**.

  - E.g., `"c:\dev", "d:\lib"` on the command line is parsed as *two* arguments:

    - `c:\dev,` (note the trailing `,`, syntactic `"` quotes stripped)
    - `d:\lib`
- **You must use the `-Command` (`-c`) option in order to pass arrays**.

  - `-Command` fundamentally changes how the arguments are parsed:

    - All arguments are stripped of syntactic (non `\"`-escaped) `"` quotes.
    - The resulting tokens are space-concatenated to form a single string.
    - The resulting string is *then* **interpreted *as PowerShell code***, i.e. as if you had submitted it from inside a PowerShell session.
  - This therefore enables all of PowerShell's features, such as passing arrays with `,`, `'...'` (single-quoting), ..., and notably also means that references to *PowerShell* variables (e.g. `$HOME`) *are* recognized (unlike with `-File`).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for more guidance on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command` (`-c`).

Therefore, the **best approach in your case** is:

```
target = "'c:\dev', 'd:\lib'" ' Note the embedded '...'-quoting
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
' Note the use of -c (-command) instead of -file
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -c .\file.ps1 -target " & target)
```

Using embedded `'...'`-quoting simplifies passing the array elements in a way that PowerShell sees them as *individually* quoted (with the values at hand, this isn't strictly necessary, but it may be in other cases).

Doing this with embedded `"..."`-quoting gets unwieldy, because each embedded `"` must then be escaped as `\""` (sic):

- `""` to escape the `"` inside the *VBScript* string,
- and `\` to ensure that `\"` is ultimately passed on the command line, which PowerShell requires for escaping `"` on the *command line*<sup>[1]</sup> (whereas PowerShell-*internally*, it is `` `" `` or (alternatively, inside a double-quoted string) `""`).

```
target = "\""c:\dev\"", \""d:\lib\"""
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
objShell.Run("powershell.exe -noexit -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -c .\file.ps1 -target " & target)
```

---

<sup>[1] While in *Windows PowerShell* you can *situationally* get away with `""` instead of `\"`, it can *break*, especially if the overall `-c` argument is enclosed in `"..."`.
This problem has been *fixed in PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where you can now use `""` and `\"` interchangeably.

E.g., when invoked from `cmd.exe`,

`powershell -c " ""ab c"".length "` *breaks*, whereas

`pwsh -c " ""ab c"".length "` *works*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following vbscript:

```
target1 = """c:\dev, d:\lib"""
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell") 
objShell.run("powershell.exe -Command .\file.ps1 -target " & target1)
```

And this powershell script:

```
param (
    [string[]]$target
)
foreach ($t in $target) {
    write-output $t
}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

Without -Command the argument is always interpreted as a single string.

Comment: Good point about the need for `-Command` if _arrays_ are to be passed. Note that the escaped embedded double quotes (`""` inside `"""c:\dev, d:\lib"""`) ultimately have no effect here and PowerShell ultimately sees the array elements as unquoted (which works fine in this case); additional work is needed if the array elements need quoting individually (which Mango99 (ineffectively) attempted), such as for elements containing spaces.