# weird powershell behaviour with a string parameter and a script file

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script file which is as follows

```
param(
[parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
[string] $db_server,
[parameter (Mandatory = $true)]
[string[]] $db_server_list

)

write-output "My DB server is $db_server"
foreach ($list in $db_server_list)
{
    write-output $list
}
```

Let us assume the file is saved as script1.ps1

On my development laptop, I can run this from visual studio code without any issues.

```
.\script1.ps1 -db_Server 'my_db_server,999' -db_server_list ("server1,5694","server2,7788")
```

It runs fine, the value of db_Server is as specified that is my_db_server,999 and i am able to loop through the db_Server_list without loosing the comma which is the port number.

I am calling the file from an external orchestration program, and to do so. I need to run

```
powershell.exe  .\script1.ps1 -db_Server 'my_db_server,999' -db_server_list ("server1,5694","server2,7788")
```

And all of a sudden i get errors.

Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'db_server'. cannott convert value to type System.string. I do not want db_server to be an array even though it has a comma, I need it back as a single string as I used this for a connection string, and if the value after the comma is stripped off, it will break my script.

Please note that this only happens when i call powershell.exe scriptfile.ps1. Running from VS code doesnt result in such errors.

Thanks all.

I have ran it again, its thesame issue.
[image]

The reason why I need to add powershell.exe is because I am calling the script from an ansible playbook.

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- **Ansible** also offers the **[`ansible.windows.win_shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_shell_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-windows-win-shell-module)** module, which uses a *shell* to process the specified command line, and that shell *is* PowerShell.

  - If you use this method, you can therefore use your original PowerShell command as-is (note that I've removed the unnecessary `(...)` around the array passed to `-db_server_list` and have switched to single-quoting):

    ```sh
    .\script1.ps1 -db_Server 'my_db_server,999' -db_server_list 'server1,5694', 'server2,7788'
    ```
- By contrast, **if you use [`ansible.windows.win_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_command_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-windows-win-command-module)**, *no* shell is involved and you must indeed call (Windows) PowerShell's CLI, [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), *explicitly*, as shown below.

---

**Note**:

- **The command below is meant to be run from *outside* PowerShell and only works there**<sup>[1]</sup>; from *inside* PowerShell, you wouldn't need to call `powershell.exe` to begin with, but if you did, you'd either have to enclose everything after `-c` in `"..."` in this case (which would also work from outside PowerShell) or, from inside PowerShell only, in `{ ... }` - but note that *neither approach is a valid test for whether a given a command line will work when called from OUTSIDE PowerShell*.
- If you were to call from `cmd.exe`, it is generally preferable to enclose the entire argument list passed to `-c` (`-command`) in `"..."`, so as to prevent inadvertent interpretation of special characters such as `&` by `cmd.exe` up front. This is *not* necessary in *shell-free* invocation scenarios, such as with `ansible.windows.win_command` or from a scheduled task, for instance.
- Either way, **if you want `"` characters to be seen by PowerShell's `-c` parameter as part of the command to (ultimately) execute, you must *escape* them as `\"`** - *unescaped* `"` characters are *stripped* during command-line parsing, which explains why your attempt didn't work: `-db_server_list ("server1,5694","server2,7788")`, when passed from outside PowerShell, is ultimately seen as
  `-db_server_list (server1,5694,server2,7788)`, which is *broken syntax*.
- By contrast, **`'` characters need *no* escaping**, and switching to using `'...'` arguments exclusively offers the simplest solution in your case.

```sh
powershell.exe -c .\script1.ps1 -db_Server 'my_db_server,999' -db_server_list 'server1,5694', 'server2,7788'
```

---

<sup>[1] The reason it doesn't work from PowerShell is that the *calling* PowerShell session interprets the `'...'` strings, and in this case passes their content *unquoted*, because the content happens not to contain space characters.</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that `pwsh`, the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI now defaults to `-File` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66066236/45375) for details on how arguments passed to `-c` (`-Command`) are parsed, juxtaposed with `-f` (`-File`) arguments, and when to use which parameter.</sup>

Comment: Read up the link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57441095/running-a-powershell-command-using-full-path-and-arguments-from-command-line/57443822#57443822

I realised that If I called the script like this

 powershell.exe -c "& .\test.ps1 -db_Server 'server1,9999' -db_server_list 'serverx,77','servery,88'"

It works.

Comment: @user5544: I've substantially revised the answer, and I hope it now clarifies the various aspects around quoting (it matters where you call from, and whether a shell is involved or not), along with an Ansible alternative. Again, `powershell.exe -c "& .\test.ps1 -db_Server 'server1,9999' -db_server_list 'serverx,77','servery,88'"` and `powershell.exe -c & .\test.ps1 -db_Server 'server1,9999' -db_server_list 'serverx,77','servery,88'` (the `&` is optional in both cases) are equivalent when no shell is involved. I've also added an Ansible alternative that allows direct use of PowerShell commands.