# PowerShell - accessing script parameters, sent from Windows cmd shell

Tags: powershell, parameters, parameter-passing, args

#### Questions

1. How can you access the parameters sent to PowerShell script (.ps1 file)?
2. Can you access parameters A: by name, B: by position, C: a mix of either?

#### Context

I recently tried to write a PowerShell script (.ps1) that would be called from a Windows batch file (.bat) (or potentially cmd shell, or AutoHotKey script) - which would pass parameters into the .ps1 script for it to use (to display a toast notification). Thanks to the instructions on [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-args.html), I have used `$args` to do this kind of thing in the past, however for some reason I could access the parameters this way (despite passing parameters, `$args[0] = ''` (empty string) and `$args.Count = 0`) so eventually had to remove all the `$args` code, and replace it with `Param()` script instead.

I'm still not quite sure why, but thought this is something I should get to the bottom of before I try to write my next script...

**Code Example 1: Args (un-named parameters)**

```powerhsell
ToastNotificationArgs.ps1
-------------------------

Write-Debug "The script has been passed $($args.Count) parameters"
If (!$args[0]) { # Handle first parameter missing }
If (!$args[1]) { # Handle second parameter missing }

Import-Module -Name BurntToast
New-BurntToastNotification -Text "$args[0], $args[1]"
```

^ I thought the above code was correct, but like I say, I kept struggling to access the parameters for some reason and could not figure out why. (If anyone can spot what I was doing wrong, please shout!)

**Is $args[] a valid approach?** I assume so given it's use of [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-args.html), but maybe there are some pitfalls / limitations I need to be aware of?

---

**Code Example 2: Param (named parameters)**

```powerhsell
ToastNotificationParams.ps1
---------------------------
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string]$Title,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string]$Message
)

Import-Module -Name BurntToast
New-BurntToastNotification -Text "$Title, $Message"
```

^ This was the only way to get my script working in the end. However when I passed the parameters in, my calling cmd script sent the parameters by position i.e. (`pwsh.exe -File "ToastNotificationParams.ps1" "This is the title" "Message goes here"`) rather than by named pairs. (Not sure if this is best practice, but is how my script was initially intended to be used to left it for now).

---

While Param() got my script working this time (and I also realise the inherent dangers of position-based parameters), there are times when a position-based approach might be necessary (e.g. the number of parameter is unknown)...

**Code Example 3: Hybrid**

```powerhsell
ToastNotificationMix.ps1
------------------------
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string]$Title
)

Import-Module -Name BurntToast
For ( $i = 1; $i -lt $args.count; $i++ ) {
    New-BurntToastNotification -Text "$Title, $args[i]"
}
```

**Is something like this valid?**.. If not (or there is a better solution), any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$PSBoundParameters` I believe is what you need.

Comment: As an aside: `$args[i]` inside `"..."` needs enclosure in `$(...)` - only variable references as a whole do not require this - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for an overview of PowerShell's expandable (interpolating) strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **The [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) is only available in *simple* (non-advanced) functions / scripts**. A script automatically becomes an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one by using the [`[CmdletBinding()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CmdletBindingAttribute) attribute and/or at least one per-parameter [`[Parameter()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute) attribute.

  - Using `$args` allows a function/script to accept an open-ended number of *positional* arguments, usually instead of, but also in addition to using explicitly declared parameters.
  - But it doesn't allow passing *named* arguments (arguments prefixed by a predeclared target parameter name, e.g., `-Title`)
- **For robustness, using an *advanced* (cmdlet-like) function or script is preferable**; such functions / scripts:

  - They require declaring parameters *explicitly*.
  - They **accept no arguments other than ones that bind to declared parameters.**

    - However, **you can define a single catch-all parameter that collects all positional arguments that don't bind to any of the other predeclared parameters, using `[Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments)]`**.
- **Explicitly defined parameters are positional *by default*, in the order in which they are declared inside the `param(...)` block**.

  - **You can turn off this default with `[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]`**,
  - which then allows you to ***selectively* enable positional binding, using the `Position` property** of the individual `[Parameter()]` attributes.
- When you call a PowerShell script via the PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh)'s `-File` parameter, the invocation syntax is *fundamentally* the same as when calling script from *inside* PowerShell; that is, you can pass *named* arguments and/or - if supported - *positional arguments*.

  - Constraints:

    - The arguments are treated as *literals*.
    - Passing *array* arguments (`,`-separated elements) is *not* supported.
  - If you do need your arguments to be interpreted as they would be from *inside* PowerShell, use the `-Command` / `-c` CLI parameter instead
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for guidance on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command.

---

To put it all together:

`ToastNotificationMix.ps1`:

```
[CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding=$false)]
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0)] 
    [string]$Title
    ,
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromRemainingArguments)] 
    [string[]] $Rest
)

Import-Module -Name BurntToast
foreach ($restArg in $Rest) {
   New-BurntToastNotification -Text "$Title, $restArg"
}
```

You can then call your script from `cmd.exe` as follows, for instance (I'm using `pwsh.exe`, the PowerShell (Core) CLI; for Windows PowerShell, use `powershell.exe`):

Positional binding only:

```
:: "foo" binds to $Title, "bar" to $Rest
pwsh -File ./ToastNotificationMix.ps1 foo bar
```

Mix of named and positional binding:

```
:: "bar" and "baz" both bind to $Rest
pwsh -File ./ToastNotificationMix.ps1 -Title foo bar baz
```