# Run Powershell script as administrator in VBA

Tags: vba, powershell

I am writing a VBA script that send parameters to a Powershell script to create AD accounts. Powershell needs to be running in administrator mode. Down below is how I call the script to run. If anyone could help me in running the application in admin mode that would be amazing!!

```
strCommand = "Powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file ""<FilePath>""<Parameters>"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "administrator mode"? Do you mean "Run as administrator"? If that's the case, why does PowerShell need to be run as administrator?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart To create AD accounts, you have to open powershell as administrator. When you don't do that, it comes up with an error saying "Access is denied"

Comment: That would normally not be the case (local elevation is a separate issue from directory service access). For example on my work computer I can run my AD management tool using a logon that is a member of Domain Admins but not a local administrator. So technically speaking what you are saying is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a file named `script.ps1` in the current directory, and arguments `foo` and `bar` (alternatively, remove `$PWD` below and specify the full script file path); `-NoExit` keeps the elevated console window that is created open after running the script:

```
strCommand = "powershell.exe -c Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe \"" -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoExit -f `\""$PWD\script.ps1`\"" foo bar \"""
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)
```

Note the need to call the [Windows PowerShell CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1), `powershell.exe`, *twice*, nested:

- First, in order to be able to run the PowerShell-internal [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet with `-Verb RunAs` so as to create an *elevated* (run-as-admin) process, which invariably runs in a *new* console window. (Note that `WshShell.Exec()` itself runs *asynchronously* and provides no direct feedback.)

  - Note that this will present the UAC security dialog to confirm the intent to create an elevated process, and that this dialog can by design only be responded to *interactively*.
- Second, as the process to be elevated in order to invoke the target script elevated.

  - *Caveat*: The elevated target process will see `C:\Windows\System32` as its working directory, not the caller's. To use the caller's working directory, you'd have to switch from a `-file` (`-f`)-based call to a `-command` (`-c`)-based one and execute a `Set-Location` statement first, which can notably also change how pass-through arguments for the script are interpreted; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).

This complicates quoting, and requires requires that the nested call's `"` characters be seen as `` `\" `` (represented as `` `\"" `` inside a *VBScript* string literal) on the outer call's command line, and the outer call's `"` as `\"` (`\""` in VBScript).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68183395/45375) for how to construct such a command line for use with many parameters (arguments) *algorithmically*, via a dictionary of parameter name-value pairs.