# How to solve problem with quotes in arguments on calling a PowerShell script with -File option?

Tags: powershell, cmd, parameter-passing, quotes, double-quotes

I want to call a small PowerShell (v5.1) script from Windows 10 Pro command line with arguments.

```
param($ReqURL, $JSONString) 
Write-Host $ReqURL # for debug 
Write-Host $JSONString # for debug 
Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $ReqURL -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json" -Body $JSONString
```

Calling the script in a PowerShell console works fine:

```
.\http-patch.ps1  -ReqURL myRESTApi -JSONString '{"lastname": "Bunny"}'
```

Calling the script from the Windows *Command Prompt* (`cmd.exe`) works when I escape the double quotes, like this:

```
PowerShell .\http-patch.ps1 -ReqURL myRESTApi  -JSONString '{\"lastname\": \"Bunny\"}'
```

But when I use the `-File` option, it fails because the `$JSONString` inside the script is equal to `'{"lastname":`:

```
PowerShell -File "C:\work\LV Demo\http-patch.ps1" -ReqURL myRESTApi  -JSONString '{\"lastname\": \"Bunny\"}'
```

I assume here are some problems with quotes, but I can't find the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the **`-File` parameter** of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the **Windows PowerShell CLI**, **only *double* quotes (`"`) are recognized** as having syntactic function **when calling from *outside* PowerShell**, such as from `cmd.exe`:

Therefore, switch from `'` to `"` (the *embedded* `"` chars. require escaping as `\"` (sic) either way):

```bash
:: From cmd.exe
PowerShell -File "C:\work\LV Demo\http-patch.ps1" -JSONString "{\"lastname\": \"Bunny\"}" -ReqURL myRESTApi
```

By contrast, when you use `-Command`, `'...'` strings *are* recognized, after unescaped `"` chars. - the only ones with syntactic function *during initial command-line parsing* - have been *stripped*, because the resulting tokens are *then* interpreted *as PowerShell code*.

For guidance on when to use `-Command` vs. `-File` and the differences in resulting parsing, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).

---

**From *inside* PowerShell, there's rarely a need to to call another PowerShell instance**, given that `.ps1` files can be invoked directly, in-process.

In cases where you do need to call the CLI from inside PowerShell - say you need to call the CLI of the *other PowerShell edition*, PowerShell (Core)'s [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), from `powershell.exe` or vice versa - the **best choice is to use a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)** (which works *only* when calling from inside PowerShell), because that:

- allows you to focus *solely* on PowerShell's own quoting and escaping requirements.
- supports receiving *typed* output (objects other than *strings*), behind-the-scenes XML-based serialization, albeit with limited type fidelity  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180367/45375).

```bash
# From PowerShell
# Note how the " chars. now need NO escaping.
# (If you were to use a "..." string, you'd escape them as `" or "")
PowerShell { 
 & C:\work\LV Demo\http-patch.ps1" -JSONString '{"lastname": "Bunny"}' -ReqURL myRESTApi 
}
```

While you *can* **call via individual arguments**, analogous to how you must call from *outside* PowerShell, you'll not only lose the benefit of typed output, but you'll also run in a **longstanding bug up to PowerShell 7.2.x that requires *manual* escaping of embedded `"` chars. as `\` when calling *external programs*** - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375) - as evidenced by one of your own attempts (here, using `'...'` is perfectly fine, because PowerShell recognizes it):

```bash
# !! Note the unexpected need to \-escape the embedded " chars.
PowerShell -File .\http-patch.ps1 -JSONString '{\"lastname\": \"Bunny\"}' -ReqURL myRESTApi  

# Variant with double quotes.
# !! Note the *double* escaping: first with ` - for the sake of PowerShell itself -
# !! then with \ due to the bug.
PowerShell -File .\http-patch.ps1 -JSONString "{\`"lastname\`": \`"Bunny\`"}" -ReqURL myRESTApi
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works from **cmd** terminal! 
Just for my interesst: Why it fails, when i call PowerShell from **PowerShell terminal**?
I get `JSONString =  {\ `

Comment: Background to my question was that I started testing **http-patch.ps1** directly from the PowerShell terminal. Happy that it worked, I wanted to call the script in a LabVIEW VI (LabVIEW does not have a native HTTP patch VI), which would be analogous to do it from **cmd.exe**. That went wrong. So I started testing different combinations, and almost went mad to find that each one behaved differently.

The script block solution looks most elegant for me.