# How to control output of powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have this simple powershell script which simply reads the arguments from stdin. Nothing else. The problem I have is that this also prints what it reads. How can I stop that? The end goal I have with this is writing a program that takes a file (input via stdin), transforms it, then outputs to stdout. But if it's going to output the input first, the whole thing won't work, so I am already blocked at the first step.

```
$lines=while($x=read-host){$x}

$lines
```

Called like this:

```
echo hello | powershell .\myScript.ps1
```

Expected output:

```
hello
```

Actual output:

```
hello
hello
```

What can I do to avoid this problem? My expectation would have been that it doesn't output the result of the assignment.

Of course I can workaround by simply taking the file name as parameter instead, but I would like to learn how this use case can be made to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *bypass* your problem by using a ***better solution* for collecting all stdin input**: the [automatic **`$input`** variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#input):

```bash
# Collect all lines from stdin.
$lines = @($input)

$lines
```

Note that `$input` is an *enumerator* for the lines of text provided via stdin, and enclosing it in `@(…)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), forces its enumeration, so that `$lines` ends up containing an *array* of lines (an `[object[]]` array containing `[string]`s) representing all stdin input.

Then, be sure to invoke your script via the `-File` parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI:

```bash
# Note the use of -File
echo hello | powershell -File .\myScript.ps1
```

Note:

- When using neither `-File` nor `-Command`, `-Command` is implied in `powershell.exe` (Windows PowerShell) (whereas it is now `-File` in [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI).
- Thus, your original command implicitly uses `-Command`, which would require use of `$input` as part of the command too:

  ```bash
  # Less efficient equivalent of the above.
  echo hello | powershell -Command "$input | .\myScript.ps1"
  ```
- However, when invoking *script files* (`.ps1`), use of `-File` is generally preferable, not least because `-Command` subjects the script path and any pass-through arguments to an *extra* round of interpretation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for guidance.

---

As for **what you tried**:

[`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) *echoes to the console* what the user types / what is provided via stdin, in addition to *returning it as data*.

*You cannot suppress this echoing from inside PowerShell*, and to the *outside caller* the echoed `Read-Host` response is indistinguishable from intentional data output.

Use of `$input` avoids this problem, and is the preferable and more efficient solution to begin with.

Comment: Perfect, that works as expected. I didn't know about the -Command / -File defaults and what they mean for $input.

Comment: @kutschkem ....

Answer (score 0):

You're outputting content twice, so you get it twice.
Just remove $lines and you're good to go :)

```
$lines=while(
    $x=read-host
    ){
        $x
    }

echo hello | pwsh .\myscript.ps1
```

I've added a pause to validate, just after the function.
[image]

Also - if you ever have an .exe that would output some sort of text you can try a few things.

#### Redirect it to null

$null = & $someExe

#### Void it

[void] (& $someExe)

#### Redirect all output to null

& $someExe *>$null

[image]

Comment: That's not helping, what I am actually trying to avoid is outputting the result of the assignment. Can you show how to do that? Can I somehow redirect the output of the assignment? Is an assignment just syntactic sugar for Set-Variable?

Comment: The undesired output is the uncontrollable side effect of collecting stdin input via repeated `Read-Host` calls: `Read-Host` prints what was "entered" directly to the console, outside PowerShell's system of output streams.
As such, you cannot silence this output from _inside_ PowerShell, and PowerShell redirections don't help (to the outside caller, this output is stdout output, just like _intentional_ output from the script).
As an aside: it doesn't make sense to use `>>` with `$null` (though it does no harm), and you probably meant `$null = ...` or `[void] (...)`, not `$void = ...`

Comment: Correct, haven't used it as of late so my mistake