# powershell missing closing ')' because of bracket in username

Tags: windows, powershell, environment-variables, parentheses, windows-11

How can i possibly fix this?
[image]

Kind Regards.

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why not simply:`PowerShell -File $env:userprofile\git\...`?

Comment: What happens if you use `& ${Env:USERPROFILE}\Git\Scr...` or `& "$Env:USERPROFILE\Git\...` or `& "${Env:USERPROFILE}\Git\...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You're calling `powershell.exe` *from PowerShell***:

- First, the question is why you're calling *another instance* of PowerShell in order to execute a script file (`*.ps1`). You could just **invoke it *directly***, which is not only simpler, but faster, due to **running in-process** ( a `(` in the user name reflected in `$env:USERPROFILE` is then *not* a problem):

  ```bash
  & $env:USERPROFILE\Git\Scripte\PowerShell\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1
  ```
- If you do **need another instance** - such as if you're calling from [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), but your script only works in *Windows PowerShell* - **use a *script block* (`{ ... }`)**, which not only avoids your problem, but also preserves rich data-type support for both input and output (within the constraints of the XML-based cross-process serialization that happens behind the scenes).

  ```bash
  powershell { & $env:USERPROFILE\Git\Scripte\PowerShell\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1 }
  ```

  - Note that this technique works *from PowerShell only*. For outside calls, a *string*-based invocation, such as the one you tried, is necessary.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `powershell "& $env:USERPROFILE\Git\Scripte\PowerShell\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"`

- If you specify neither `-File` nor `-Command` with `powershell.exe`, `-Command` is implied (note that for `pwsh.exe`, the *PowerShell (Core) 7+* CLI, it is now `-File`).
- What follows `-Command`, after removal of (unescaped) `"` during command-line parsing, is then interpreted as PowerShell code.
- Because you're calling from PowerShell and are using an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), the reference to environment variable `$env:USERPROFILE` is expanded *before* the child process sees the resulting command-line string, which is the source of your problem:

  - PowerShell ends up executing something like `& C:\User\user(a\...`, which - due to the *unescaped* `(` - causes a syntax error.
  - Therefore, there are two solutions (though the script-block technique shown above is still preferable:

    - Either: Use `'...'` rather than `"..."` around the (implied) `-Command` argument.

      ```bash
       powershell '& $env:USERPROFILE\Git\Scripte\PowerShell\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1'
      ```
    - Or: Escape the `$` in `$env:USERPROFILE` as `` `$ `` to prevent premature expansion (this is helpful if you need *selective* up-front expansion):

      ```bash
       # Note the ` (backtick) before $
       powershell "& `$env:USERPROFILE\Git\Scripte\PowerShell\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1"
      ```

An alternative, as [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) points out, is to use the `-File` parameter:

```bash
powershell -File $env:USERPROFILE\Git\Scripte\PowerShell\Wallpaper_Slideshow.ps1
```

- What is passed to `-File` - both the script file path itself and any subsequent pass-through arguments, are *not* subject to another round of interpretation as PowerShell code, so the `(` in the environment-variable value doesn't cause a problem.
- For detailed guidance on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375).