# powershell closes immediatly after running neofetch (windows terminal)

Tags: windows, powershell, syntax, windows-10, command-line-interface

I installed neofetch using scoop, and have it in the settings.json for powershell:

```
"commandline": "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe neofetch -nologo",
```

the `neofetch` makes it close immediately after printing the last line of the neofetch.

tried using -noexit to no avail, hopefully i can get it to just boot and use neofetch becuase i like the way it looks lol

Comment: PowerShell's own command line switches need to go before any user arguments: `powershell.exe -noexit -nologo neofetch`

Answer (score 2):

[Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen) has
provided the crucial pointer:

- The **PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s *own* parameters** - such as `-NoLogo` in your case, and often `-ExecutionPolicy`, `-NoProfile` and `-NoExit` - **must be placed *before* any command or script file to invoke** and its subsequent pass-through arguments.
- Anything that follows `-File` or `-Command` - or in the absence of either - the first argument that *isn't a CLI parameter*<sup>[1]</sup> is considered the script file or command to execute, with all *subsequent* arguments getting  *passed through, whatever they are*.

Therefore:

- `powershell.exe neofetch -nologo` is the same as `powershell.exe -Command neofetch -nologo` and passes `-nologo` to *`neofetch`* instead of to PowerShell, which presumably causes it to fail and exit right away.
- You would have to place `-nologo` *before* `neofetch` to work as intended; however, `-nologo` isn't actually necessary in your case (with `-Command` and `-File`, `-nologo` is *implied*, except if `-File` is combined with `-NoExit`); to demonstrate the **correct syntax** with `-NoExit` instead:

```bash
# -NoExit (as well as any other PowerShell CLI parameters) must come *first*.
# Same as: 
#   powershell.exe -NoExit -Command neofetch
powershell.exe -NoExit neofetch
```

In the context of your JSON file:

```json
"commandline": "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit neofetch",
```

---

<sup>[1] Note that the CLIs of the two PowerShell editions have *different defaults*: [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI,, defaults to `-Command`, whereas [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, defaults to `-File`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) for when to use `-File` vs. `-Command`.</sup>