# Executing powershell script from javascript (Discord.js command)

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, discord.js

**TL;DR:** `const spawn=require('child_process').spawn; spawn('powershell.exe', ['D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1']);` doesn't work

Hello,

I am using discord.js to make a bot, i want a command to execute a **powershell script** when it's called, the command handling, registering works fine, but the execution of the script isn't successful.

Here is the code of my command:

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const authorizedUsers = ['...', '...'];

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('start_server')
        .setDescription('Start the minecraft modded server.'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        // If the user is authorized to run the command
        if (authorizedUsers.includes(interaction.user.id)) {
            console.log('Starting minecraft server');

            spawn('powershell.exe', ['D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1']);

            console.log('Minecraft server started !');
            await interaction.reply('Minecraft server started !');
        }
        else {
            await interaction.reply('You can\'t use this command');
        }
    },
};
```

The two messages are correctly sent in the console, the bot also replies to my message in discord, but **the script isn't executed**...

Can you help me with this ?

Comment: Inspect the error output from the process object returned by `spawn`. You likely need `spawn('powershell.exe', ['-File', '"D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1"']);`, reviewing the error output will help you confirm

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i tried `console.log(spawn('powershell.exe', ['-File', '"D:/Dev/VSC/bots/Courage Bot/test.ps1"']));` but in the console output i have no error, and all the fields like _hadError_, _closeAfterHandlingError_, _errored_ and _errorEmitted_ are either **false**, either **null**.

Comment: Of course there's no error anymore, you switched to the correct command line syntax :) For troubleshooting your original, make sure you wait until the process exits if you want to see the actual exit code and any terminating error message.

Comment: But my script isn't executed, i replaced the code of the script with someone that copies a file to another location, when i execute it from windows explorer (right click > execute with powershell) the file is copied, so i delete it, and try starting it using the code, but my file don't get copied !
When i manually run the script, the powershell console starts for fraction of seconds, and then close nearly-instantly, but with the child_process.spawn no console is started.

Comment: Again: make sure you wait until the spawned process exits - otherwise you'll never see the actual exit code or any terminating error messages iit might have output.

Comment: The process never exists because it never begins, nothing happen, no powershell console spawns, just nothing.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the original problem:

> `spawn('powershell.exe', ['D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1'])`

This fails, because the default parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, is `-Command`,<sup>[1]</sup> which means that, translated to a process command line, your call is equivalent to:

```bash
# !! BROKEN, due to -Command
powershell.exe -Command "D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1"
```

This is *broken*, because `-Command` strips the `"` chars. during initial command-line parsing and *then interprets the result as PowerShell code*, resulting in a - broken - attempt to execute
`D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1` (the lack of quoting makes this *two* arguments).

The simple - and preferable for *script-file invocation* - solution is to use the `-File` parameter, where *no* additional interpretation of the CLI arguments is performed:

```bash
# OK, due to -File
powershell.exe -File "D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1"
```

The way to express the above via a `spawn` call is:

```bash
spawn('powershell.exe', ['-File', 'D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1'])
```

Note that there is *no* need for *embedded* quoting, because `spawn` will ensure that `'D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1'` is placed as `"D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1"` on the `powershell.exe` process command line.

By contrast, if you did want to solve this via (implied) `-Command`, you *would* need embedded quoting, and also `&`, PowerShell's call operator, which is needed whenever a command to execute is *quoted*.

```bash
# Translates to:
#   powershell.exe "& \"D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1\""
spawn('powershell.exe', ['& "D:/Dev/My Bot/test.ps1"'])
```

See also:

- [Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) on when to use `-File` vs. `-Command` in PowerShell CLI calls.

---

<sup>[1] By contrast, [`pwsh.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the PowerShell (Core) CLI, now defaults to `-File`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const scriptPath = '"D:\\PATH_TO_FOLDER_WHERE_SCRIPT_IS_LOCATED\\start.ps1';
const command = `powershell.exe -File ${scriptPath}`;

exec(command, (error) => {
    if (error) {
        console.error(`Error executing PowerShell script: ${error}`);
        return;
    }

    console.log('Script executed successfully!');
});
```

Thank you for your help !